# How to determine stationarity of a component of a VAR process?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, stationarity, vector-autoregression

Could you please say I am right or wrong in the following exercise attached.
Sorry for I couldn't type formula here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first part (from the equation starting with $y_{2,t}$) contains an error. Note that there are the lags of $y_{1,t}$ rather than $y_{2,t}$ on the right hand side. Therefore, you cannot write the lag polynomial $1-0.6L-L^2=0$ (while you could if there were lags of $y_{2,t}$ on the right hand side instead).

The second part (from the equation starting with $y_{1,t}$) is not correct either. You cannot ignore the fact that there are some lags of $y_{2,t}$ on the right hand side when considering the stationarity of $y_{1,t}$. For example, it would suffice for $y_{2,t}$ to be nonstationary to make $y_{1,t}$ nonstationary even if the lag polynomial for $y_{1,t}$ by itself indicated stationarity.